# How to get the name of cover page of word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have to make a .NET application (in C#) using Word interop in which I want to read a Word file and find the name of the cover page.

[Here](https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ah-Jh2Ok5SuHbZxlkEaWihO1geU) I put a sample file. I added a cover page (named as “Austin”) to the file. I want the name (“Austin”) of the cover page. I searched with Google but didn't find any help.

Comment: What have u tried so far ?? any codes???

Comment: @MohitShrivastavathnks for you time. just open a file and try to read the corresponding property. checked in all the property in debug modebut did find any helpful information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the cover page that is displayed in the Word UI is not inserted in the file name. It is just used to identify the cover page building block in the corresponding building block template (the name of the template is shown in the *Building Block Organizer* that can be reached via *Insert > Quick Parts > Building Block Organizer*).

You therefore won't be able to retrieve the name of the cover page from the document.